# Unable to change input methods in fcitx

Tags: elementary-os, input-method, fcitx

I have installed several fcitx chinese input methods but I am unable to switch input methods.

This is the output I copied from the terminal after executing: `fcitx-diagnose`

```
# System Info:
1.  `uname -a`:

        Linux austin-elementary 4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

2.  `lsb_release -a`:

        No LSB modules are available.
        Distributor ID: elementary
        Description:    elementary OS 0.4 Loki
        Release:    0.4
        Codename:   loki

3.  `lsb_release -d`:

        Description:    elementary OS 0.4 Loki

4.  `/etc/lsb-release`:

        DISTRIB_ID="elementary"
        DISTRIB_RELEASE=0.4
        DISTRIB_CODENAME=loki
        DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="elementary OS 0.4 Loki"

5.  `/etc/os-release`:

        NAME="elementary OS"
        VERSION="0.4 Loki"
        ID="elementary"
        ID_LIKE=ubuntu
        PRETTY_NAME="elementary OS 0.4 Loki"
        VERSION_ID="0.4"
        HOME_URL="http://elementary.io/"
        SUPPORT_URL="http://elementary.io/support/"
        BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementary/+filebug"

6.  Desktop Environment:

    Desktop environment is `gnome3`.

7.  Bash Version:

        BASH_VERSION='4.3.46(1)-release'

# Environment:
1.  DISPLAY:

        DISPLAY=':0'

2.  Keyboard Layout:

    1.  `setxkbmap`:

            xkb_keymap {
                xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
                xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
                xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
                xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)+group(alt_shift_toggle)" };
                xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
            };

    2.  `xprop`:

            _XKB_RULES_NAMES(STRING) = "evdev", "pc105", "us", "", "grp:alt_shift_toggle"

3.  Locale:

    1.  All locale:

            bg_BG.utf8
            C
            ca_AD.utf8
            ca_ES.utf8
            ca_ES.utf8@valencia
            ca_FR.utf8
            ca_IT.utf8
            cs_CZ.utf8
            C.UTF-8
            da_DK.utf8
            en_AG
            en_AG.utf8
            en_AU.utf8
            en_BW.utf8
            en_CA.utf8
            en_DK.utf8
            en_GB.utf8
            en_HK.utf8
            en_IE.utf8
            en_IN
            en_IN.utf8
            en_NG
            en_NG.utf8
            en_NZ.utf8
            en_PH.utf8
            en_SG.utf8
            en_US.utf8
            en_ZA.utf8
            en_ZM
            en_ZM.utf8
            en_ZW.utf8
            hu_HU.utf8
            id_ID.utf8
            ja_JP.utf8
            ko_KR.utf8
            nb_NO.utf8
            nl_AW
            nl_AW.utf8
            nl_BE.utf8
            nl_NL.utf8
            pl_PL.utf8
            POSIX
            sv_FI.utf8
            sv_SE.utf8
            th_TH.utf8
            tr_CY.utf8
            tr_TR.utf8
            uk_UA.utf8
            vi_VN
            vi_VN.utf8
            zh_HK.utf8
            zh_TW.utf8

    2.  Current locale:

            LANG=en_US.UTF-8
            LANGUAGE=en_US
            LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
            LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
            LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
            LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
            LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
            LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
            LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
            LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
            LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
            LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
            LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
            LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
            LC_ALL=

4.  Directories:

    1.  Home:

            /home/austin

    2.  `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}`:

        Environment variable `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is not set.

        Current value of `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is `~/.config` (`/home/austin/.config`).

    3.  Fcitx Settings Directory:

        Current fcitx settings directory is `~/.config/fcitx` (`/home/austin/.config/fcitx`).

5.  Current user:

    The script is run as austin (1000).

# Fcitx State:
1.  executable:

    Found fcitx at `/usr/bin/fcitx`.

2.  version:

    Fcitx version: `4.2.9.1`

3.  process:

    Found 2 fcitx processes:

         2611 fcitx
         2886 fcitx-dbus-watc

4.  `fcitx-remote`:

    `fcitx-remote` works properly.

# Fcitx Configure UI:
1.  Config Tool Wrapper:

    Found fcitx-configtool at `/usr/bin/fcitx-configtool`.

2.  Config GUI for gtk2:

    **Config GUI for gtk2 not found.**

3.  Config GUI for gtk3:

    Found `fcitx-config-gtk3` at `/usr/bin/fcitx-config-gtk3`.

4.  Config GUI for kde:

    **`kcmshell4` not found.**

# Frontends setup:
## Xim:
1.  `${XMODIFIERS}`:

    **Environment variable XMODIFIERS is "@im=ibus" instead of "@im=fcitx". Please check if you have exported it incorrectly in any of your init files.**

    **Please set environment variable XMODIFIERS to "@im=fcitx" using the tool your distribution provides or add `export XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx` to your `~/.xprofile`. See [Input Method Related Environment Variables: XMODIFIERS](http://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Input_method_related_environment_variables#XMODIFIERS).**
    **If you are using `gnome>=3.6`, you may want to uninstall `ibus`, remove `ibus-daemon` or use the command `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active false` to disable IBus integration in order to use any input method other than `ibus`. See [Note for GNOME Later than 3.6](http://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Note_for_GNOME_Later_than_3.6) for more detail.**

    Xim Server Name from Environment variable is ibus.

2.  XIM_SERVERS on root window:

    Xim server name is the same with that set in the environment variable.

3.  XIM for Emacs:

    **Your LC_CTYPE is set to en_US.UTF-8 instead of one of zh, ja, ko. You may not be able to use input method in emacs because of an really old emacs bug that upstream refuse to fix for years.**

## Qt:
1.  qt4 - `${QT4_IM_MODULE}`:

    **Environment variable QT_IM_MODULE is "ibus" instead of "fcitx". Please check if you have exported it incorrectly in any of your init files.**
    **You may have trouble using fcitx in qt4 programs.**

    **Please set environment variable QT_IM_MODULE to "fcitx" using the tool your distribution provides or add `export QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx` to your `~/.xprofile`. See [Input Method Related Environment Variables: QT_IM_MODULE](http://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Input_method_related_environment_variables#QT_IM_MODULE).**

2.  qt5 - `${QT_IM_MODULE}`:

    **Environment variable QT_IM_MODULE is "ibus" instead of "fcitx". Please check if you have exported it incorrectly in any of your init files.**
    **You may have trouble using fcitx in qt5 programs.**

    **Please set environment variable QT_IM_MODULE to "fcitx" using the tool your distribution provides or add `export QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx` to your `~/.xprofile`. See [Input Method Related Environment Variables: QT_IM_MODULE](http://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Input_method_related_environment_variables#QT_IM_MODULE).**

3.  Qt IM module files:
    Found fcitx im module for Qt5: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libfcitxplatforminputcontextplugin.so`.
    Found fcitx im module for Qt4: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/inputmethods/qtim-fcitx.so`.

## Gtk:
1.  gtk - `${GTK_IM_MODULE}`:

    **Please set environment variable GTK_IM_MODULE to "fcitx" using the tool your distribution provides or add `export GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx` to your `~/.xprofile`. See [Input Method Related Environment Variables: GTK_IM_MODULE](http://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Input_method_related_environment_variables#GTK_IM_MODULE).**

2.  `gtk-query-immodules`:

    1.  gtk 2:

        **Cannot find `gtk-query-immodules` for gtk 2**

        **Cannot find fcitx im module for gtk 2.**

    2.  gtk 3:

        **Cannot find `gtk-query-immodules` for gtk 3**

        **Cannot find fcitx im module for gtk 3.**

3.  Gtk IM module cache:

    1.  gtk 2:

        Found immodules cache for gtk `2.24.30` at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules.cache`.
        Version Line:

            # Created by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk2.0-0/gtk-query-immodules-2.0 from gtk+-2.24.30

        Found fcitx im modules for gtk `2.24.30`.

            "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-fcitx.so" 
            "fcitx" "Fcitx (Flexible Input Method Framework)" "fcitx" "/usr/share/locale" "ja:ko:zh:*" 

    2.  gtk 3:

        Found immodules cache for gtk `3.18.9` at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules.cache`.
        Version Line:

            # Created by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0 from gtk+-3.18.9

        **Failed to find fcitx in immodule cache at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules.cache`**

        **Cannot find fcitx im module for gtk 3 in cache.**

4.  Gtk IM module files:

    1.  gtk 2:

        All found Gtk 2 immodule files exist.

    2.  gtk 3:

        All found Gtk 3 immodule files exist.

# Configuration:
## Fcitx Addons:
1.  Addon Config Dir:

    Found fcitx addon config directory: `/usr/share/fcitx/addon`.

2.  Addon List:

    1.  Found 27 enabled addons:

            fcitx-autoeng
            fcitx-chttrans
            fcitx-classic-ui
            fcitx-clipboard
            fcitx-dbus
            fcitx-freedesktop-notify
            fcitx-fullwidth-char
            fcitx-googlepinyin
            fcitx-imselector
            fcitx-ipc
            fcitx-keyboard
            fcitx-kimpanel-ui
            fcitx-lua
            fcitx-notificationitem
            fcitx-pinyin
            fcitx-pinyin-enhance
            fcitx-punc
            fcitx-quickphrase
            fcitx-remote
            fcitx-rime
            fcitx-spell
            fcitx-unicode
            fcitx-vk
            fcitx-x11
            fcitx-xim
            fcitx-xkb
            fcitx-xkbdbus

    2.  Found 0 disabled addons:

3.  Addon Libraries:

    All libraries for all addons are found.

4.  User Interface:

    Found 2 enabled user interface addons:

        fcitx-classic-ui
        fcitx-kimpanel-ui

## Input Methods:
1.  Found 5 enabled input methods:

        fcitx-keyboard-us
        rime
        pinyin
        shuangpin
        googlepinyin

2.  Default input methods:

    You have a keyboard input method "fcitx-keyboard-us" correctly added as your default input method.

# Log:
1.  `date`:

        Wed Oct  5 16:51:19 BST 2016

2.  `~/.config/fcitx/log/`:

        total 0

3.  `~/.config/fcitx/log/crash.log`:

    `~/.config/fcitx/log/crash.log` not found.
```

I tried manually clicking onto googlepinyin by i'm still only able to type in english

Answer (score 5):

ok so the solution is to set your default input method to fcitx through im-config

run this in the terminal :

```
im-config
```

then choose fcitx

Answer (score 0):

Tried to refer to **Source:[fcitx cannot launch --current](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/fcitx-cannot-launch-current-4175418957/#post6250909)**